# How to replace values in dataframe columns based on certain conditions

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe `u`

```
   u<- data.frame(a=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7"),b=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011),c1=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.5),c2=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.5),c3=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.5))
a   b       c1  c2  c3
x1  2005    0.5 0.5 0.5
x2  2006    0.5 0.5 0.5
x3  2007    0.5 0.5 0.5
x4  2008    0.6 0.6 0.6
x5  2009    0.7 0.7 0.7
x6  2010    0.9 0.9 0.9
x7  2011    0.5 0.5 0.5
```

I want to replace values in column (c1,c2,c3) based on values in column b. So if the value in column b is less than 2008, replace values in column (c1,c2,c3) to 1,2 and 3. The resulting data frame is

```
 a  b     c1    c2  c3
x1  2005    1   2   3
x2  2006    1   2   3
x3  2007    1   2   3
x4  2008    0.6 0.6 0.6
x5  2009    0.7 0.7 0.7
x6  2010    0.9 0.9 0.9
x7  2011    0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: Try `u[which(u$b<2008),3:5] <- rep(1:3,each=3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using libraries, or in case you need to generalize this to many c columns, you can do:

```
u <- data.frame(a=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7"),
b=c(2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011),
c1=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.5),
c2=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.5),
c3=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,0.5))
```

Then use normal brackets notation to subset, and assign the three columns at once:

```
u[u$b<2008,3:5] <- data.frame(1,2,3)
u
   a    b  c1  c2  c3
1 x1 2005 1.0 2.0 3.0
2 x2 2006 1.0 2.0 3.0
3 x3 2007 1.0 2.0 3.0
4 x4 2008 0.6 0.6 0.6
5 x5 2009 0.7 0.7 0.7
6 x6 2010 0.9 0.9 0.9
7 x7 2011 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`library(magrittr)`

`u$c1 %<>% ifelse(u$b < 2008, 1, .)`

`u$c2 %<>% ifelse(u$b < 2008, 2, .)`

`u$c3 %<>% ifelse(u$b < 2008, 3, .)`

Answer (score 0):

I happen to find this to be more intuitive but just a preference.

`u$c1[u$b < 2008] <- 1
u$c2[u$b < 2008] <- 2
u$c3[u$b < 2008] <- 3`

Answer (score 0):

and another way...

```
library(dplyr)
u %>%
  mutate(c1 = ifelse(b < 2008, 1, c1),
         c2 = ifelse(b < 2008, 2, c2),
         c3 = ifelse(b < 2008, 3, c3)
        )
```